# MVC model binder sometimes does not work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I have a very odd behavior. I'm sending some complex object via ajax stringified as JSON.
I have the same class structure for the models as for the javascript data, so it should easily be mapped to the model. And it works in most cases, however in some cases the Statements from a ThenClause do not get mapped to the model:

JSON data that is sent from the client:

[image: JSON data that is sent from the client]

Model that I get in the controller:

[image: Model that I get in the controller]

Does anybody have any idea why in some cases the model binder doesn't work?

A JSON that works fine:

> {"dqsName":null,"propertyTypes":[],"dqsTemplateId":0,"sections":[{"SectionType":2,"conditionsSortOrder":2,"disableAddField":true,"Conditions":[{"FieldId":23,"OperatorId":131,"SortOrder":1,"Values":[{"DqsValueId":0,"DqsConditionId":0,"Value":"12-12-2015"}],"selectedValues":[null]}],"SortOrder":0,"ThenClause":{"Statements":[{"DqsStatementId":0,"DqsValue":"0","FieldId":1,"SortOrder":0}],"statementSortOrder":1,"disableAddField":true},"ElseClause":{"Statements":[{"DqsStatementId":0,"DqsValue":0,"FieldId":1,"SortOrder":0}],"statementSortOrder":1,"disableAddField":true}}],"sectionSortOrder":1,"disableAddElse":true,"disableAddStandalone":true,"baseScore":0}

A JSON that does not work:

> {"dqsName":null,"propertyTypes":[],"dqsTemplateId":0,"sections":[{"SectionType":2,"conditionsSortOrder":1,"disableAddField":true,"Conditions":[{"FieldId":8,"OperatorId":135,"SortOrder":0,"Values":[{"DqsValueId":0,"DqsConditionId":0,"Value":"12-12-2015"},{"DqsValueId":0,"DqsConditionId":0,"Value":"12-13-2015"}],"selectedValues":[null,null]}],"SortOrder":1,"ThenClause":{"Statements":[{"DqsStatementId":0,"DqsValue":0,"FieldId":1,"SortOrder":0}],"statementSortOrder":1,"disableAddField":true},"ElseClause":{"Statements":[{"DqsStatementId":0,"DqsValue":0,"FieldId":1,"SortOrder":0}],"statementSortOrder":1,"disableAddField":true}}],"sectionSortOrder":2,"disableAddElse":true,"disableAddStandalone":true,"baseScore":0}

Some other things that I observed is if for the JSON that does not work I have a null ElseClause, the ThenClause is bound correctly. But if I have some data in the ElseClause, the ThenClause won't be bound correctly(Statements will be null).

Comment: You need to compare the difference between one that works and one that doesn't. Without the models here, we can't really help.

Comment: i will post an example of a JSON that works and one that doesn't, i couldn't find any significant difference

Comment: I've updated the description, the only thing that I can think about is that both ElseClause and ThenClause have a Statements array, and somehow the model binder does not know how to handle them, but in some cases is does... I'm confused

Comment: In the one that doesn't work, this: `"DqsValue": 0` is different from the one that does work. The one that does work has the value surrounded by quotes: `"DqsValue": "0"`